# Calling Java method from HTML file

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web application, and the following Java method will be called dynamically several times when the application's web page is opened in a browser:

Java:

```
public String getProductImgURL (int i) // image at index i
{
    return products_to_display.get(i).getImage();
}
```

I want to be able to call this function in for loop in the HTML file, I tried making the calls using JavaScript's document.write in the following way, however it didn't work.

Part of the JavaScript inside HTML file:

```
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
        document.write(
        "<img src=\"@model.getProductImgURL(i)\">"+
        "<br>"
        );
   }
```

It doesn't work, the weird thing is that when I pass a constant number to the function above in JavaScript, it works just fine!

I'm new to this, can anyone help me find a way calling the Java function above in the HTML file using JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you cannot call a serverside method via clientside code. they are not the same thing, they dont live on the same machines etc..

you will need to make an http call to a server that will call the java method.

Comment: Is it possible to get clearer directions/example please?

Comment: no, your question is too broad - I don't have time to explain how the internet works

Comment: Before I posted the question I made some research on the internet.

From stuff I read, I think the solution can be AJAX, however I didn't really understand how I can use it. Especially the part of combining AJAX and where the Java method call. That  is an example of what I mean by "directions"  - I'm not asking from anyone to explain how the WHOLE internet works.

Comment: sorry, but your question is still to broad. you want me to explain how client server applications work? you can google that.